# Connect failed :IO::Socket::INET: connect: timeout is showing up in Perl .

Tags: perl, scripting

I have wriiten this script to send mail through gmail smtp to my gmail account . It is not working and giving the already mentioned error ?

```
use Net::SMTP::TLS;  

my $mailer = new Net::SMTP::TLS(  
    'smtp.gmail.com',  
    Hello   =>      'smtp.gmail.com',  
    Port    =>      587,  
    User    =>      'cetranger@gmail.com',  
    Password=>      'xxxxxx');  

$mailer->mail('cetranger@gmail.com');  

$mailer->to('cetranger@gmail.com');  

$mailer->data;  

$mailer->datasend("Sent from perl!");  

$mailer->dataend;  

$mailer->quit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Simple;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS;

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS->new(
    host     => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port     => 587,
    username => 'cetranger@gmail.com',
    password => 'xxxxxx'
);

my $message = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        From           => 'cetranger@gmail.com',
        To             => 'cetranger@gmail.com',
        Subject        => 'Sent from perl!',
    ],
    body => 'Sent from perl!',
);

sendmail( $message, {transport => $transport} );
```

Answer (score 1):

This script should work in fact (I tested with my own gmail account successfully).

I suspect you have some firewall in-between that prevent you from connecting to gmail.
Could you try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from your host. You should have something like that:

```
host$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 173.194.67.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP da8sm6658151wib.6
```

If you do not have the last 3 lines, this means that you cannot connect directly to the gmail server. Then check as well your own firewall settings (if any).