# sending email from perl

Tags: windows, perl, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to implement a step to send an email from gmail, from perl.
I was trying this with difeerent modules:

- use [`Email::Send::Gmail`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Send::Gmail);
- use [`Mail::Sendmail`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::Sendmail);
- use [`Net::SMTP::TLS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP::TLS);

using examples from internet but nothing has worked

here are the scripts I wrote:

1).

```
#!C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe

use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Send;
use Email::Send::Gmail;
use Email::Simple::Creator;
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        From    => 'xxx@gmail.com',
        To      => 'zzz@yahoo.com',
        Subject => 'alert! please have a look',
    ],
    body   => 'Dear Ionut, Please have a look on the following error. Thank you, the server.',

);

my $sender = Email::Send->new(
    { mailer => 'Gmail',
      mailer_args => [
        username => 'xxx@gmail.com',
        password => '12345678',
      ]
    }
);

eval {$sender->send($email)};
die "Error sending mail: $@" if $@;
```

the errors received:

```
Error sending mail: Email::Send::Gmail: error connecting to server smtp.gmail.com at C:\Users\ipreda\perl5\lib\perl5/Email/Send.pm line 256.
```

---

2).

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use Mail::Sendmail;
my $to_list = 'xxx@yahoo.com';
my $cc_list = 'aaa@yahoo.com';
my $bcc_list = '';
my $email = "Dear you, \n\nPlease have a look on the following error. \n\nThank you, \n\nthe server.\n";
my $MailFrom = 'aaa@yahoo.com';
my $subject = "alert! please have a look";
my $message = "module test";
%mail = (
    To => $to_list,
    From => $MailFrom,
    Bcc => $bcc_list,
    Cc => $cc_list,
    Subject => $subject,
    Message => $message
);
$mail{Smtp} = 'smtp.gmail.com';
sendmail(%mail);
```

the error is

```
Global symbol "%mail" requires explicit package name at D:\_Perl - tutorials\send_email_1.pl line 12
Global symbol "%mail" requires explicit package name at D:\_Perl - tutorials\send_email_1.pl line 20
Global symbol "%mail" requires explicit package name at D:\_Perl - tutorials\send_email_1.pl line 21
Execution of D:\_Perl - tutorials\send_email_1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

---

3).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SMTP::TLS;

my $smtp = new Net::SMTP::TLS(
    'smtp.gmail.com',
    Port    =>  587,
    User    =>  xxx@gmail.com',
    Password=>  '12345678',
    Timeout =>  60
);

#  -- Enter email FROM below.   --
$smtp->mail('xxx@gmail.com');

#  -- Enter recipient mails addresses below --
my @recipients = ('aaa@yahoo.com', 'bbb@yahoo.com');
$smtp->recipient(@recipients);

$smtp->data();

#This part creates the SMTP headers you see
$smtp->datasend('To: aaa@yahoo.comn');
$smtp->datasend("From: me n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Type: text/html \n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: A Test Mail");
# line break to separate headers from message body
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("This is a test mail body");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->dataend();

$smtp->quit;
```

the error

```
Connect failed :IO::Socket::INET: connect: 10060 
at D:\_Perl - tutorials\send_email_2.pl line 6.
```

I guess it is not about the code but maybe some settings in firewall?!

Can anyone tell me what settings should i modify, if my guess is right or point me out the error , please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: #2 - you just need to declare `my %mail`. It might work after that!

Comment: #3 - try the solution posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326241/connect-failed-iosocketinet-connect-timeout-is-showing-up-in-perl

Comment: #1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704058/perl-emailsendgmail-cannot-connect-to-gmail-account-on-windows-7

Comment: @ccheneson: I was performing the updates described in the topic you mentioned but same error occurred.

Comment: @ialarmedalien: I added `my` in front of `%email` becoming `my %mail` but still no email was sent. Also no error was reported.

Comment: Do you have any firewall software running? Are you on a network that might be blocking outgoing access on certain ports? There are lots of potential issues that could be causing the failure to send messages, unfortunately!

Comment: @ialarmedalien: I am at work. Yes, most probably, the network firewall could block the outgoing access ...:( . I will try at home and come back with details.